# How to generate a 3D image based on ChArUco calibration of two 2D images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, triangulation

I'm currently extracting the calibration parameters of two images that were taken in a stereo vision setup via `cv2.aruco.calibrateCameraCharucoExtended()`. I'm using the `cv2.undistortPoints()` & `cv2.triangulatePoints()` function to convert any two 2D points to a 3D point coordinate, which works perfectly fine.

I'm now looking for a way to convert the 2D images, which can be seen under approach 1, to one 3D image. I need this 3D image because I would like to determine the order of these cups from left to right, to correctly use the triangulatePoints function. If I determine the order of the cups from left to right purely based on the x-coordinates of each of the 2D images, I get different results for each camera (the cup on the front left corner of the table for example is in a different 'order' depending on the camera angle).

### Approach 1: Keypoint Feature Matching

I was first thinking about using a keypoint feature extractor like SIFT or SURF, so I therefore tried to do some keypoint extraction and matching. I tried using both the Brute-Force Matching and FLANN based Matcher, but the results are not really good:

Brute-Force
[image: image description]

FLANN-based
[image: image description]

I also tried to swap the images, but it still gives more or less the same results.

### Approach 2: ReprojectImageTo3D()

I looked further into the issue and I think I need the `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()` [[docs]](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d) function. However, to use this function, I first need the Q matrix which needs to be obtained with `cv2.stereoRectify` [[docs]](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify). This stereoRectify function on its turn expects a couple of parameters that I'm able to provide, but there's two I'm confused about:

- R – Rotation matrix between the
  coordinate systems of the first and
  the second cameras.
- T – Translation vector between
  coordinate systems of the cameras.

I do have the rotation and translation matrices for each camera separately, but not between them? Also, do I really need to do this stereoRectify all over again when I already did a full calibration in ChArUco and already have the camera matrix, distortion coefficients, rotation vectors and translations vectors?

### Some extra info that might be useful

I'm using 40 calibration images per camera of the ChArUco board to calibrate. I first extract all corners and markers after which I estimate the calibration parameters with the following code:

```
(ret, camera_matrix, distortion_coefficients0,
 rotation_vectors, translation_vectors,
 stdDeviationsIntrinsics, stdDeviationsExtrinsics,
 perViewErrors) = cv2.aruco.calibrateCameraCharucoExtended(
    charucoCorners=allCorners,
    charucoIds=allIds,
    board=board,
    imageSize=imsize,
    cameraMatrix=cameraMatrixInit,
    distCoeffs=distCoeffsInit,
    flags=flags,
    criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS & cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10000, 1e-9))
```

The board paremeter is created with the following settings:

```
CHARUCO_BOARD = aruco.CharucoBoard_create(
    squaresX=9,
    squaresY=6,
    squareLength=4.4,
    markerLength=3.5,
    dictionary=ARUCO_DICT)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: from R and T you can compute the 3D space homography (4x4 matrix) that is needed to transform the standard camera to your actual camera's pose. The inverse transformation will be just the matrix inverse. Let's call tA the transformation of cam A and tB for cam B, then the transform from cam A to B is: tA2B = tB*tA.inv()

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Micka ! So you're suggesting me to do `tA2B = tB*tA.inv()` to obtain the T and the same for R, then use the `cv2.stereoRectify` to obtain Q and then use `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()`?

Comment: you'll need the combined transformation of T and R I guess, not sure whether they can just be separately calculated. If the transformation between the cameras is the only thing you are missing, then stereoRectify should be possible afterwards, because if I'm not missing something, tA2B should just be the transformation between cam A and cam B there (and tB2A = tA2B.inv()).